# Deep merge two already existing entity framework entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, code-first

Here's my scenario.  We have a Customers table, with various navigation properties (1-1, 1-many, many-many, etc) to say Orders, which have OrderItems etc.. (read very deep object graph)

Very simple example:
**Customer1 has Orders[1..5] while Customer2 has Orders[6..9]**

Now there comes a time when we find out that the two customers are actually one in the same and we'd like to merge the two: **Customer1.Merge(Customer2);**

After the merge, we should see **Customer1 has Orders[1..9] along with all other properties of Customer2, and Customer2 is empty and can safely be deleted.**

Now I've came across a pretty old post about deep cloning (http://www.urmanet.ch/?p=11), which results in a **NEW entity**, but I have two **Existing Entities** which need to be reduced down to **One Existing Entity that has added the object graph of the second entity where I can then delete the second entity and commit the unit of work.**  With this example originating in 2008, and with the newer versions of EF now available, I'm wondering whats the **correct** way to achieve this?

I like the idea of an extension method that would perform this task generically (meaning reflection) so that when / if the entity model changes (new properties / relationships being added etc.), **this generic Merge method would not need to change**...

Here is the base code I am starting with, and I'd like to modify it so that it can merge two entities, not create a new entity (clone).

```
/// This class is used to store self references for
/// back tracking
public class SelfReferencesTracking
{
    public string EntitySetName;
    public EntityObject NewEntityObject;
    public EntityKey OriginalKeys;
}

/// Extension method class for the EntityObject class
public static class EntityObjectExtension
{
    //Enable tracking
    private static readonly List<SelfReferencesTracking> Tracking =
        new List<SelfReferencesTracking>();

    /// These method makes a 1:1 copy of the original entity object
    /// 
    /// The original entity object /// The copied entity object
    public static EntityObject Clone(this EntityObject entityObject)
    {
        //Get constructor for new object
        object newEntityObject = entityObject.GetType().GetConstructor(new Type[0]).Invoke(new object[0]);

        Tracking.Add(new SelfReferencesTracking
            {
                EntitySetName = entityObject.EntityKey.EntitySetName,
                OriginalKeys = entityObject.EntityKey,
                NewEntityObject = (EntityObject) newEntityObject
            });

        //Copy all properties and its values of the given type
        PropertyInfo[] properties = entityObject.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            try
            {
                object propertyValue = property.GetValue(entityObject, null);
                PropertyInfo myProperty = property;
                if (!entityObject.EntityKey.EntityKeyValues.Any(x => x.Key == myProperty.Name))
                {
                    //Ignore all properties of these types
                    if (property.PropertyType != typeof (EntityKey) &&
                        property.PropertyType != typeof (EntityState) &&
                        property.PropertyType != typeof (EntityReference<>))
                    {
                        //Check, if the property is a complex type (collection), in that
                        //case, some special calls are necessary
                        if (
                            property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (EdmRelationshipNavigationPropertyAttribute), false)
                                    .Count() == 1)
                        {
                            //Check for self referencing entities
                            if (propertyValue.GetType() == entityObject.GetType())
                            {
                                //Get the self referenced entity object
                                var selfRefrencedEntityObject = (EntityObject) property.GetValue(entityObject, null);

                                //This variable is used to store the new parent entity objects
                                EntityObject newParentEntityObject = null;

                                //This loops might be replaced by LINQ queries... I didn't try that
                                foreach (
                                    SelfReferencesTracking tracking in
                                        Tracking.Where(
                                            x =>
                                            x.EntitySetName == selfRefrencedEntityObject.EntityKey.EntitySetName))
                                {
                                    //Check, if the key is in the tracking list
                                    foreach (
                                        EntityKeyMember newKeyValues in
                                            selfRefrencedEntityObject.EntityKey.EntityKeyValues)
                                    {
                                        //Iterate trough the keys and values
                                        foreach (
                                            EntityKeyMember orgKeyValues in tracking.OriginalKeys.EntityKeyValues)
                                        {
                                            //The key is stored in the tracking list, which means, this is
                                            //the foreign key used by the self referencing property
                                            if (newParentEntityObject == null)
                                            {
                                                if (orgKeyValues.Key == newKeyValues.Key &&
                                                    orgKeyValues.Value == newKeyValues.Value)
                                                {
                                                    //Store the parent entity object
                                                    newParentEntityObject = tracking.NewEntityObject;
                                                }
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                                //Set the value to the new parent entity object
                                property.SetValue(newEntityObject, newParentEntityObject, null);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //Entity collections are always generic
                                if (propertyValue.GetType().IsGenericType)
                                {
                                    //Don't include self references collection, e.g. Orders1, Orders2 etc.
                                    //Check for equality of the types (string comparison)
                                    if (
                                        !propertyValue.GetType()
                                                      .GetGenericArguments()
                                                      .First()
                                                      .FullName.Equals(entityObject.GetType().FullName))
                                    {
                                        //Get the entities of the given property
                                        var entities = (RelatedEnd) property.GetValue(entityObject, null);

                                        //Load underlying collection, if not yet done...
                                        if (!entities.IsLoaded) entities.Load();

                                        //Create a generic instance of the entities collection object
                                        Type t =
                                            typeof (EntityCollection<>).MakeGenericType(new[]
                                                {property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0]});

                                        object newEntityCollection = Activator.CreateInstance(t);

                                        //Iterate trough the entities collection
                                        foreach (object entity in entities)
                                        {
                                            //Add the found entity to the dynamic generic collection
                                            MethodInfo addToCollection =
                                                newEntityCollection.GetType().GetMethod("Add");
                                            addToCollection.Invoke(newEntityCollection,
                                                                   new object[] {Clone((EntityObject) entity)});
                                        }

                                        //Set the property value
                                        property.SetValue(newEntityObject, newEntityCollection, null);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var baseType = propertyValue.GetType().BaseType;
                            if (baseType != null && baseType.Name == "EntityReference")
                            {
                                //Simply copy the EntityKey to the new entity object’s EntityReference
                                ((EntityReference) property.GetValue(newEntityObject, null)).EntityKey =
                                    ((EntityReference) property.GetValue(entityObject, null)).EntityKey;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //Common task, just copy the simple type property into the new entity object
                                property.SetValue(
                                    newEntityObject,
                                    property.GetValue(entityObject, null), null);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (InvalidCastException ie)
            {
                //Hmm, something happend...
                Debug.WriteLine(ie.ToString());

                continue;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Hmm, something happend...
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());

                continue;
            }
        }
        return (EntityObject) newEntityObject;
    }
}
```

**To recap: I would like some help in converting this Clone extension method into a Merge extension method, and I am hoping an expert could step in and help complete the picture.  Any help is greatly appreciated!**

Comment: Have a look at [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper).